# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Select Case When date between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, case

I have a table Like this :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| UserID | Amount   | PayDate                |TransactionType|  ...
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1        | 140      | 2014-09-30 22:00:00.000|  7            |
| 2        | 230      | 2014-09-30 22:00:00.000|  7            |
| 1        | 120      | 2014-08-01 22:00:00.000|  7            |
| 2        | 135      | 2014-07-30 22:00:00.000|  7            |
| 1        | 120      | 2014-09-30 22:00:00.000|  4            |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I wrote the below query but it returns NULL, Please advise on this query as is:

The declared below dates are between 29/09/2014 and 1/10/2014

```
Declare
   @dateStart datetime= CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETUTCDATE())+2),GETUTCDATE()),101),
   @dateEnd datetime=(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETUTCDATE())-1),GETUTCDATE()),101))

Select 
   MemberID,
   case 
      when transactionType = 7 
           and (PayDate  between  @dateStart and @dateEnd) then Amount
   End AS 'Outstanding Amount'
from 
   MemberPayment
```

My output should be :

```
   | MemberID | OutStanding Amount|
   ---------------------------------
   |  1       |   140             |
   |  2       |   230             |
```

but the query returns null, what am I doing wrong ?  Is the CASE When DATE between DATES used correct in SQL Server 2008 R2 ?

PS: Please note I do not want to change the query to have WHERE Condition.

Thank you in advance stack overflow family.

Comment: `(CreatedDate between CreatedDate and @dateEnd)` should be `(CreatedDate between @dateStart and @dateEnd)`, not?

Comment: @MikhailTimofeev my mistake corrected it, initially its like that its returning Null.

Comment: you need to have else part becoz when transactionType != 7 and (CreatedDate  not between CreatedDate and @dateEnd) you will get NULL values!!!!

Comment: i think u must be use Paydate column instead of CreatedDate column.M i right?

Comment: May I ask why you don't want a WHERE condition?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I wanted to understand why would CASE When date between dates isn't returning desired results, without.

Comment: Still not getting desired results after editing my query based on all the suggestions.

Comment: @TMAN-MAN Your case returns a valid value between the dates, and nothing (null) outside the dates. You still get all rows, just with null values.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work

```
Declare
   @dateStart datetime= DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETUTCDATE())+2),GETUTCDATE()),
   @dateEnd datetime=DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETUTCDATE())-1),GETUTCDATE())

   select MemberID, [Outstanding Amount]
   from
   (
Select 
   UserID as MemberID,
   case 
      when transactionType = 7 
           and (PayDate  between  @dateStart and @dateEnd) then Amount
   End AS 'Outstanding Amount'
from 
   MemberPayment
   ) As TmpQuery

   where [Outstanding Amount] is not null
```

I removed the convert to varchar from both of your variables.

Then i put a select around your query, to filter just the results with Oustanding Amount not NULL.
Please take note, that I selected UserID as MemberID, because u used UserID in your example.

I tested it with a table, where PayDate is a Datetime Column.

As already mentioned in one of your comments i would prefer the easy method (and it`s much faster!):

```
Declare
   @dateStart datetime= DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETUTCDATE())+2),GETUTCDATE()),
   @dateEnd datetime=DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETUTCDATE())-1),GETUTCDATE())

   select UserID, Amount as [Outstanding Amount]
   from MemberPayment
   where TransactionType = '7'
   and PayDate between @dateStart and @dateEnd
```